# Redirecting in java

Tags: java, jsp

A Web Dynamic project on eclipse,

In a .jsp file I read the username and password from the user and called the logging function in the class below

The function should validate the username and password then redirect to to a different .jsp page

The redirection part below is Not working and has errors..

```
 package myPackage;
import java.sql.* ;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class javaMethods extends HttpServlet   {


public String logging(String user_id, String password){
    ResultSet request = null;
    Statement stmt =null; 
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users", "root", "maram");
    stmt=conn.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usersData WHERE id = '"+user_id+"'");


        if(rs.next()) //if username was found
        {
             if (rs.getString(2).equals(password))
                {

                 if(rs.getString(3).equals("admin"))
                    {

                     ////REDIRECTING///
                    response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
                    response.setHeader("Location", "admin.jsp");
                    }
                 else
                    {
                    ////REDIRECTING///
                    response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
                    response.setHeader("Location", "welcome.jsp");
                    }
                }
            else //incorrect password
                {
                System.out.println ("Incorrect password");
                }

        }
    else //user name does not exist
        {
        System.out.println ("Username does not exist");
        }
}

}
```

Comment: "... and has errors“ - a StackTrace could be helpful ^^

Comment: error in resolving the type of response @Alexander

Comment: See @Andrii's answer. You need to overwrite `doGet()` and pass the `response` variable to your method. Btw. where do `String user_id` and `String password` from?  Are these `response.getParameter("user_id")`... ?

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look to 
[Redirecting a request using servlets and the "setHeader" method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204768/redirecting-a-request-using-servlet)

You should implement special [interface methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) which have references for request and response object references.
For example,

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Your code do not have references for that objects, response even not exists

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i dont undetstand something, but redirection from jsp looks like

```
response.sendRedirect(params);
```

In your code you just change response of the same page.