# Modify response URL with filter before servlet redirects (Java/Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, servlets, httpresponse, servlet-filters

I'm trying to modify the response URL of a `servlet` using a `servlet filter`, **before** the servlet itself issues a `response.sendRedirect`. But I'm getting nowhere with this. I first tested with the servlet and then I setup some dummy `JSP` pages to replicate the same basic behavior of the servlet. The servlet is from a third party vendor and cannot be modified.

I'll stick with the JSP pages for this question and pretend they cannot be modified. If I could modify the servlet, there wouldn't be a need to post this question.

I also referenced the two topics below to help me build the filter.

[Redirecting a request using servlets and the "setHeader" method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204768/redirecting-a-request-using-servlets-and-the-setheader-method-not-working)

[Looking for an example for inserting content into the response using a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736328/looking-for-an-example-for-inserting-content-into-the-response-using-a-servlet-f)

What's happening in the servlet/JSP is it loads with`https` and then it builds a new `URL` based on the current URL, with `http`, appending a `querystring parameter`, cacheid, and reloads the page, i.e.

1. https://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp
2. http://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp?cacheid=123456

I want it to look like this:

1. https://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp
2. https://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp?cacheid=123456

So my idea is build a filter which intercepts the response, **before** the servlet/JSP issues the response.sendRedirect, modify the location and status headers and it should work. But it's not quite working.

**testfilter.jsp**

```
<%

if (request.getParameter("cacheid") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("http:/example.com/test/testfilter.jsp?cacheid=123456");
}

%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Test</body>
</html>
```

**Filter**

Here is my `doFilter` method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("BEFORE filter");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

    if ( ((HttpServletRequest)request).getParameter("cacheid") == null ) {
        // Not sure how to append querystring parameter
        responseWrapper.setHeader("location", "https://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp?cacheid=123456");
        responseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
    }       

    chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

    String servletResponse = new String(responseWrapper.toString());

    out.write(servletResponse + " filtered"); // Here you can change the response

    System.out.println("AFTER filter, original response: " + servletResponse);

    if ( ((HttpServletRequest)request).getParameter("cacheid") == null ) {
        // Not sure how to append querystring parameter
        responseWrapper.setHeader("location", "https://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp?cacheid=123456");
        responseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
    }  
}
```

Minor issue is I'm not sure how to append the querystring parameter, cacheid, and its value in this modified response.

**Major issue is the filter seems to only fire the second time testfilter.jsp is called (with the querystring parameter, cacheid).** Here's the raw response:

**https://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Location: http://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp?cacheid=123456
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=66ACCD1EFF485CE820BB9E705311C31D; Path=/test; Secure
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 19:18:54 GMT
```

**http://example.com/test/testfilter.jsp?cacheid=123456**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 60
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1342FB2D65F5568AC7EA1EF21E6FB8E4; Path=/test
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 19:18:54 GMT

<html>
<head></head>
<body>Test</body>
</html> filtered
```

If I can just get the filter to intercept it the very first time, before it sends its own redirect, I'd be set. But things don't ever seem to be that simple.

I hope I explained it well enough, what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. Did you found a solution or a work-around for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a Nginx and move such logic into Nginx directive proxy_redirect is a workaround.